# Creating a document in Firebase Transaction and getting the doc ref

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to make a transaction where I create a document and then I need the reference of that document.

```
await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {

             const caRef = transaction.create(closedActivityRef, activityData);
}
```

So the create function doesen't exist, and with set I don't get the reference of the doc (I want to create a document with automatic key from firebase.
Thanks for your help

Comment: When you create a new document with id made by firebase you getting `DocumentReference<any>` and you can read id it gets.

Comment: How can i make that the document id is created by firebase in code?

Answer (score 0):

Becouse of you have a mistake in code here is how you should use `await` command. Becouse of transaction is made to queue document updates from many users there are no option to create document with random id generated wirh firebase. So if you want to create a new document with generated id just do it using `addDoc()` function. Or you can create new document with custom id using `.set()` method.

```js
async runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
    const documentRef = doc(db, 'posts', docId)
    await transaction.set(documentRef, activityData);
}
```

Comment: I get the same error Error: TypeError: transaction.create is not a function

Comment: @VondeTaconadis what version of firebase you use ?

Comment: I'm using firebase 9 9.1.3

Comment: @VondeTaconadis Well translate me in your language what does "Error: TypeError: transaction.create is not a function" mean.

Comment: That the function doesen't exist. With set I can't create a doc and get the ref back, I saw some code where they were using transaction.create

Comment: @VondeTaconadis Bravo now you can handle errors on your own. XD